# MediatR - NotificationHandler order of execution, naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr

I am trying to use `MediatR` to prepare a message `PrepMessageHandler` and then send to customer via two possible ways: `SendSmsHandler`, and `SendEmailHandler`

A trivial way is to do like this

```
DoAsync(){
  var msg = await _sender.Send(new PrepMessageHandler());
  if(flags.SendSms) await _sender.Send(new SendSmsHandler(msg));
  if(flags.SendEmail) await _sender.Send(new SendSEmailHandler(msg));
}
```

But seems the above violates Open Close principle: what if I later have a third `SendLetterHandler` ? i.e., I don't want to keep modifying `DoAsync()` in this case

I can do like this:

```
DoAsync(){
  var msg = await _sender.Send(new PrepMessageHandler());
  _mediator.Publish(new MsgPreparedEvent());
}
```

and have `SendSmsNotificationHandler` and `SendEmailNotificationHandler`

1. Curious which of the 2 handlers gets executed first?
2. Also what would be a good naming convention? `SendSmsNotificationHandler` could be misunderstood as a handler of `SendSmsNotificationRequest`
   But `MsgPreparedNotifHandlerWithSms` looks too long.
3. Now **both** NotifHandlers will be instantiated, but that may be unnecessary depending on `flags`. Any pattern to only instantiate the really necessary handler?
4. Last but most importantly, what are the best practice to handle this handler situation?

Comment: Use a factory design. Instantiate a concrete handler according to the flag (parameter) put through the factory. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm, it would solve the open-close issue, there is always only one handler running (if you only allow one flag). Name length is redundant, comprehensible code is not. (You're writing not for yourself, but for someone else ... ).

Comment: 1. If im not wrong, all handlers will be called at the same time but you could set up a quick console app and verify.

2. Type names are never too big as long as they are descriptive imo. Maybe in your scenario SendMessageNotificationHandler would work.

3. Dont think so, you will have to run a check on the flag, which shouldnt be a problem.

4. Best practices are already enforced by MediatR. The event is published and the handler consumes it. Voilá.